# Making Conversion/Event Pixel Load only on a specific % of page loads

Tags: php, javascript, pixel

I have a secure image pixel (example below)being used to track conversions and I only want it to load 50% of the time, what is the easiest way to do this?

```
<img src="https://tt1.zedo.com/ads2/t?o=376447;h=1231184;z=[timestamp]" width="1" height="1" BORDER="0">
```

Comment: What do you mean 50% of the time?  Do you mean randomly, or every other time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store some counter in the session.

example:

```
$_SESSION['counter']++;
if ($_SESSION['counter'] % 2 == 0) {
 echo '<img src="https://tt1.zedo.com/ads2/t?o=376447;h=1231184;z=[timestamp]" width="1" height="1" BORDER="0">';
}
```

Comment: Will php session with a counter work for different users or only if the same user tries to load the pixel again? What I need is for the conversion pixel to load on one user, and not on the next user, over and over.

Comment: this would work at user level, so it would work if the same user try to reload. If you want to do something globally you can use the same technique but simply store the counter in a database or in a key-value storage(like memcache)

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this without PHP, on the client side
    if(Math.random>0.5)
        $('body').append("")